# Allow a user to click off select2 and keep free text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5.1, jquery-select2

I currently have a select2 dropdown, version 4.0, that allows the selection of items as well as free text to be typed.

```
    $("#dropdown").select2({
        placeholder: "Select or enter a new item",
        allowClear: true,
        tags: true
    });
```

I understand that typing free text creates a new option that can be clicked or will appear as an entry if the return key is pressed.

However clicking the newly entered option or hitting return are the **ONLY** ways for it to be accepted. This seems a little unintuitive as I know users will want to click onto other form elements or tab through the form.

Is there a way to allow a tag to be created just from de-focusing the form element?

I'm thinking something along the lines of having a `.blur()` event fire a selection or have `select2:close` cause a selection but I can't quite put it together.

Comment: What version of select2 are you using ? please try to make a jsFiddle with your code so it's easy to track and work around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the `selectOnClose` option. This will select the highlighted option when the drop down is closed.